# How can I get a continuous polygon using EmguCV?

Tags: c#, .net, emgucv

I am using EmguCV 2.3.0.1416 from a simple console application (.net 4.0 and c#) and I have a question around canny's, edge detection etc.  Given the following code:

```
var colours = new[]
                  {
                      new Bgr(Color.YellowGreen),
                      new Bgr(Color.Turquoise),
                      new Bgr(Color.Blue),
                      new Bgr(Color.DeepPink)
                  };

// Convert to grayscale, remove noise and get the canny
using (var image = new Image<Bgr, byte>(fileName)
    .Convert<Gray, byte>()
    .PyrDown()
    .PyrUp()
    .Canny(new Gray(180),
           new Gray(90)))
{
    // Save the canny out to a file and then get each contour within
    // the canny and get the polygon for it, colour each a different
    // colour from a selection so we can easily see if they join up
    image.Save(cannyFileName);

    var contours = image
        .FindContours(CHAIN_APPROX_METHOD.CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE,
                      RETR_TYPE.CV_RETR_EXTERNAL);

    using (var debug = new Image<Bgr, byte>(image.Size))
    {
        int colIndex = 0;
        for (; contours != null; contours = contours.HNext)
        {
            Contour<Point> poly = contours
                .ApproxPoly(contours.Perimeter*0.05,
                            contours.Storage);

            debug.Draw(poly, colours[colIndex], 1);

            colIndex++;
            if (colIndex > 3) colIndex = 0;
        }

        debug.Save(debugFileName);
    }
}
```

I get this output (this is actually just a part of the image but it shows what I am asking about):

[image: Canny Edge]

As you can see it has a blue line with a little bit of pink and then a green line.  The real thing has just a solid edge here so I want this to be a single line in order that I can be sure it is the edge of what I am looking at.

The original image looks like this (I have zoomed it but you can see it has a very distinctive edge that I was expecting to be able to find easily).

[image: Orignal]

If I look at just the canny I can see the gap there so I tried adjusting the parameters for creating the canny (the threshold and linking threshold) but they have made no difference.

I also dilated and then eroded the canny (using the same value for the iterations parameter - 10 incidentally) and that seemed to do the trick but could I lose accuracy by doing this (it just feels a bit wrong somehow)?

So, how should I ensure that I get a single line in this instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try smoothing before canny?

I found this link, maybe useful for you

http://www.indiana.edu/~dll/B657/B657_lec_hough.pdf

Comment: Do you mean calling the SmoothMedian method (there are a few)?  I just tried that but it did not make any difference.

Comment: @kmp Well, can you do binary thresholding? If it does not affect your purpose, please apply it. Maybe the blurry edges of your image are causing it.

Comment: There is a ThresholdBinary method that takes two arguments:  http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/2.0.0.0/html/046038a6-4e0e-ba4c-d01f-eb3fc1c29383.htm - what would I put in for these values?  Also, will doing this affect the accuracy with regards finding the edge?

Comment: It won't affect the accuracy if you use correct threshold value. About the thresholding: first value is the threshold value which can determine if color should be converted into maxValue color. You can experiment the value with TRACKBAR controller. Please use like this: yourgrayimg.ThresholdBinary(trackBar.Value, new Gray(255));

Comment: Excellant!  That's done the trick (passed in "new Gray(200)" to the first argument and it has joined it up perfectly).

Comment: @kmp Did you offer a bounty in this question? I thought I was getting +50, but did not receive any. Kinda confused :|

Comment: Someone else offered the bounty but I accepted your answer so thought that would mean you would get the bounty (as I didn't offer it I couldn't manually assign it but thought that if you got the accepted answer you would get it - maybe ask on meta why you didn't get it)

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you mean by single line? Perhaps you are trying to thicken your line:

```
debug.Draw(poly, colours[colIndex], 2);
```

Instead of:

```
debug.Draw(poly, colours[colIndex], 1);
```

Or whatever thickness of line you want.
[Here's](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/1.3.0.0/html/0a782cc3-56c8-3ee4-2f73-85bf82912702.htm) the emgucv Draw Method for polygon.
Perhaps look at [this](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Shape_%28Triangle,_Rectangle,_Circle,_Line%29_Detection_in_CSharp) link too.

Comment: Thanks but I do not mean the drawing part (I just draw them to show the issue) but what I am trying to do is get fewer polygons to draw in the first place - so that emgu would be detecting just a single line (where the black meets the white in the second image).

Comment: Sorry about that. I somehow misunderstood you.

Answer (score 0):

The first argument in the approxPoly() function is exactly what you are looking for.  Just fiddle with that and you will get exactly what you want.